# How to rename multiple table names with REMAP_TABLE

Tags: oracle, remap, datapump

I have a dump file which contains several tables (A, B, C).

How can I rename these tables (A -> x, B -> y, C -> z) during data import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remapping multiple table names is possible with comma separated table names as following example:

```
impdp user/pass directory=my_dp_dir remap_schema=src_schema:dest_schema
REMAP_TABLESPACE=src_ts:dest_ts
REMAP_TABLE=src_schema.A:x,src_schema.B:y,src_schema.C:z
dumpfile=dump_file.dmp logfile=impdp.log
```